# ffmpeg compile error __wrap_swr_convert

Tags: c++, linux, ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile ffmpeg from sources and can't resolve this issue

YASM    libswresample/x86/resample.o

STRIP   libswresample/x86/resample.o

CC  libswresample/x86/resample_init.o

CC  libswresample/x86/w64xmmtest.o

LD  libswresample/libswresample.so.101

`__wrap_swr_convert' referenced in section`.text' of /tmp/cc6tTYGS.ltrans4.ltrans.o: defined in discarded section `.text' of libswresample/x86/w64xmmtest.o (symbol from plugin)

`__wrap_swr_convert' referenced in section`.text' of /tmp/cc6tTYGS.ltrans6.ltrans.o: defined in discarded section `.text' of libswresample/x86/w64xmmtest.o (symbol from plugin)

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

library.mak:110: recipe for target 'libswresample/libswresample.so.101' failed
make: *** [libswresample/libswresample.so.101] Error 1

Linux Debian 8.1

please help me

Comment: Are you using this guide to compile it [https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

w64xmmtest should only be used on Windows. I think you used configure --enable-xmm-clobber-test on Linux. Don't do that.